# Form input focus issue on page load

Tags: angular

I have a Angular 7.1 project. Have a sidebar at left. The issue is when I click on the sidebar menu item the focus remains on the menu. I want to move the focus to the first field of the form loaded on the right side on page load.

For example for the below link if I click on the "Form" link on the sidebar, the page should focus on the "Name" field on page load.

https://www.primefaces.org/omega-ng/#/components/forms

I have tried the autofocus method but with no success. Also tried the approac of the below link but did not help.

https://www.codementor.io/@yomateo/auto-focus-with-angular-7-the-directive-osfcl7rrv

Has anyone faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your input you want to focus an ID

```
<input #myInput/>
```

Then get a reference to it in the code

```
@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;
```

Then set that input's focus where appropriate. For instance, if you click your sidebar "Form" link I assume a new component is shown for the resulting page shown. In that component's onInit

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.myInput.nativeElement.focus(); 
}
```